# TFT touchscreen with Coral Dev Boards?

Tags: google-coral

I'm wondering if anyone has gotten a tft touchscreen to work with a Coral Dev Board? I have a Coral Dev Board Mini as well as several 2.4 and 2.8 inch Adafruit mini-hat touch screens and would love to know if anyone has gotten any of the Adafruit TFTs (or ANY TFT display) to work with a coral dev board. I've tried and have basically gotten nowhere. Adafruit website says it supports the Coral boards through CircuitPython, Blinka, etc. and I've followed the install instructions with no luck getting a TFT to work. Any success story or help much appreciated.
Thanks,
--dave

Answer (score 0):

The DSI interface is not currently enabled. You can follow this patch https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/d0a15d32e9a56f67954eb6b9d19b895901787319 to understand how to enable a display panel. This patch is for reference only as it is applicable to Tianma display that has been tested with the Coral dev board and not the Dev board Mini.